# Python 2D numpy.ndarray slicing without comma

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Recently someone told me to extract the first two columns of a 2D `numpy.ndarray` by

```
firstTwoCols = some2dMatrix[:2]
```

Where is this notation from and how does it work?

I'm only familiar with the comma separated slicing like

```
twoCols = some2dMatrix[:,:2]
```

The `:` before the comma says to get all rows, and the `:2` after the comma says for columns 0 up to but not including 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

firstTwoCols = some2dMatrix[:2]

This will just extract the first 2 rows with all the columns.

twoCols = some2dMatrix[:,:2] is the one that will extract your first 2 columns for all the rows.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you describe does not extract the first two columns; it extracts the first two rows. If you specify less slices than the dimension of the array, NumPy treats this as equivalent to all further slices being `:`, so

```
arr[:2]
```

is equivalent to

```
arr[:2, :]
```

for a 2D array.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand the question but...

If you do:

```
>>> Matrix = [[x for x in range(1,5)] for x in range(5)] 
>>> Matrix
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

doing `Matrix[:2]`, it will select the first two list in `Matrix`, `[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]`. But if you do:

```
>>> Matrix[:,:2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

But if you work with a Numpy, do:

```
Matrix = np.array(Matrix)

>>>Matrix[:, :2]
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: The comma-separated slicing thing is NumPy syntax.

Comment: @user2357112 oh cool! I didn't know... I updated my answer. Thanks!